What defines a room that crossing it would require you to make a new Bracha
BH
Hi,
I was told correct me if I’m wrong according to Lubavitch minhag
every time you cross from one room to the next and you return to the room you were in before, if you had food there that you made a bracha on that is less importance status than bread or wine such as anything that is haetz, hadama, or shehakol, if you said the bracha on them before you crossed into the other room and came back to the food you originaly said a bracha on you have to say a new bracha because the actual physical crossing of the room terminated your previous bracha and you have to make a new one.
So if it is actually the physical crossing of the room that forces you to make a new bracha what defines a room that crossing it would make you say the new bracha?
Or is it just the crossing of the door?
Does crossing between two beams for example terminate the existing bracha as well?
Is there anything like sub rooms that can terminate existing brachas as well that be created within in a room if yes how?

It's not a minhag, it's halacha: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4637898/jewish/Seder-Birkas-HaNehenin-Chapter-9-The-Laws-Pertaining-to-Interruptions-and-Leaving-Ones-Place-Between-Eating-and-Reciting-a-Blessing.htm#v11

And it only applies if the original location is not visible from where you moved. So your cases would probably be fine. But the question is still relevant for when there's a visual obstruction, because that only necessitates a new bracha once you're in another room (per halacha 19 ibid.).

That is one doozy of a run on...

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

This is not only "according to Lubavitch" - see Shulchan Aruch and Mishna Brura Siman 178
and these articles by way of example Brachot when changing places by Rabbi David Sperling
and New Beracha after Moving Between Rooms
By way of summary this is taken from Rabbi Sperling's answer which responds to questions about moving from one floor of a house to another and from one end to the other of a long room:

Thank you for your question. The laws of changing location as it
effects blessings on food are complex indeed. You will need to spend
some time learning the subject in depth (there are some wonderful
books in English, including "The Halachos of Brochos" by Rabbi
Bodner).
Here are short answers for your particular questions – changing
locations from room to room inside one house is a matter of debate
amongst the early Rabbis. Because of this, one is well advised to have
intent before saying a blessing that one intends to eat the food in
all the rooms of the house. If such intent was in mind at the time of
the blessing, one can move from room to room freely, and no new
blessing is needed. If one did not have such intent in mind, we nonetheless follow the opinion that no new blessing is needed. (See Biur
Halacha 178,1 "BeBeit Echad").
Moving from one side of a room to another, even in a very large hall,
does not require a new blessing to be said. (See Shulchan Aruch
178,1). This is true even if you cannot see your first location.
The ability to see your first location outside of one building is also
a matter of debate. Because of this debate we try to avoid such
situations. However, if one did in fact, for example, leave the house
to their yard from where one can still see the room they said the
first bracha in, they should not say a new blessing. (The exemption is
where there is a walkway or street between the two locations, when
even if one can see the first location a new blessing is needed).

I hope this will be of some help to you.

If one did not have such intent in mind, we nonetheless follow the opinion that no new blessing is needed. I think this is where the Alter Rebbe differs. See the link in my comment above.

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

You might want to make that comment under the question. Otherwise I don't think it will notify OP.
